# Error in MongoDB Realm when i try to get CustomData from a user

Tags: c#, mongodb, unity-game-engine, realm

when I try to access my users' CustomData in MongoDB Realm I get this error:

`An error occurred while logging in: Element 'username' does not match any field or property of class Datauser.`

I'm using Unity and .NET Sdk of Realm.

This is the SyncModel provided by Realm

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Realms;
using MongoDB.Bson;
public partial class Datauser : IRealmObject
{
    [MapTo("_id")]
    [PrimaryKey]
    public ObjectId? Id { get; set; }
    [MapTo("avatar")]
    public string? Avatar { get; set; }
    [MapTo("user")]
    public string? User { get; set; }
    [MapTo("username")]
    public string? Username { get; set; }
}
```

And this is the code I am using to retrieve data

```
 await _realmUser.RefreshCustomDataAsync();
  Datauser customData = _realmUser.GetCustomData<Datauser>();
  Debug.Log(customData);
```

CustomData is enabled and the field that connects it to the database is 'user'.
Also, using this code:

```
await _realmUser.RefreshCustomDataAsync();
 var customData = _realmUser.GetCustomData();
 Debug.Log(customData);
```

It works and I get everything returned as a string.
Solutions?

[Table Db](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fg8bL.png)

Comment: can you show the db table layout?

Comment: Done, https://i.stack.imgur.com/fg8bL.png

Comment: Much as Im not a MongoDB user, I dont see anywhere in your code where you reference the tablename.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I'm not sure about Realm, but will this code work: `_realmUser.GetCustomData<BsonDocument>()`? If so, what result you get for the case when approach with typed deserialization fails

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that the Realm SDK uses two different technologies for mapping data to C# objects. For database/sync use cases, it uses RealmObjects and their respective attributes (i.e. `MapTo`), but for deserialization of json/bson data, it uses the MongoDB.Bson library, which has its own data mapping attributes - i.e. `BsonElement`. We realize this is counterintuitive and plan to address it in a future version of the SDK, but for now you'll need to double-annotate your classes or use dedicated bson-annotated models for API that deserialize from json (i.e. any API that has an overload returning `BsonDocument`). More concretely, to fix your immediate issue change your model to:

```cs
public partial class Datauser : IRealmObject
{
    [MapTo("_id")]
    [PrimaryKey]
    public ObjectId? Id { get; set; }

    [MapTo("avatar")]
    [BsonElement("avatar")]
    public string? Avatar { get; set; }

    [MapTo("user")]
    [BsonElement("user")]
    public string? User { get; set; }

    [MapTo("username")]
    [BsonElement("username")]
    public string? Username { get; set; }
}
```